# Rewrite URL with version number in Nginx

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Digital Ocean + Nginx server, which hosts several websites. Now, I want to manage several versions for one website. So I need to add a version number to its urls, and want to apply the following rules:

1) Let's assume the current version number is `1`. Any url without a version number like `www.myweb.com/action/...` (where `action` could be anything except a version number) should be rewritten automatically to `www.myweb.com/1/action/...`.

2) Urls having different version numbers will be treated by different servers (ie, codebase + database) listening to different ports (eg, `3000` and `8080`).

The follows is my current nginx config file, does anyone know how to modify it to apply **the 1st rule (we may implement the 2nd rule later)**?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myweb.io www.myweb.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myweb.io www.myweb.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-......-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location = / {
        return 301 /home;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: is this fully resolved, or do you still require help / bounty is available for a better answer?

Comment: it is fully resolved, and i just awarded an answer my bounty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need a simple rewrite for urls where first path is not a number. So i would add below for Rule 1

```
location ~* ^/[^0-9]+/? {
  rewrite .* /1$request_uri redirect;
}
```

This will make sure any path not starting with a number get redirected to correct path with application version. Below is the test results of same

```
$ curl -I localhost/1/tarun
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 18:46:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I localhost/tarun
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 18:46:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Location: http://localhost/1/tarun
Connection: keep-alive
```

When you want to implement **Rule #2**, you should use a map

```
map $request_uri $app_port {
    ~ "^/1/" "3000";
    ~ "^/2/" "3001";
    ~ "^/3/" "3002";
    default "3000";
}

server  {
  location / {
    ....
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$app_port$request_uri$is_args$args;

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works... Then, do you have any idea about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034913/change-the-url-base-before-routing)?